Macro to open PDF file in Adobe Acrobat Pro
I have tried the below code to open pdf file in Adobe Acrobat Pro. It opens the file dialogue and allows me to select the pdf file. Once i select the pdf file it gives error " THERE WAS AN ERROR OPENING THIS DOCUMENT. THE FILE CANNOT BE FOUND." Any help would be great.
Sub Get_Pdf()
Dim XLName As String, PDFPath As String, READERPath As String
Dim OpenPDF, sh As Worksheet

XLName = ThisWorkbook.Name
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
PDFPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="PDF file (*.pdf), *.pdf")
If UCase(PDFPath) = "FALSE" Then Exit Sub
'~~> Below path differs depending Adobe version and installation path
' READERPath = "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe "
READERPath = "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe "
Shell READERPath & PDFPath, vbNormalFocus: DoEvents

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2")

SendKeys "^a", True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2")

SendKeys "^c"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2")

Windows(XLName).Activate
sh.Paste sh.Range("A1")
SendKeys "%{F4}", True
End Sub



If you are talking about Adobe Acrobat Pro why opening the file in this way and not adding a reference and deal with what you need without SendKeys which is so unreliable? 2. Then, do you have installed Adobe Acrobat Pro 64 bits? What about a debugging line (after ): Debug.Print Dir("C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe)? What does it return in Immediate Window? 3. Using Shell you need to place the arguments between double quotes: shell ("""" & "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe & """ """ & PDFPath & """"), if the paths involve spaces.


The suggested way works with or without parenthesis. Parenthesis in such a case only evaluates the string, which si not necessary to be evaluated. Is is something you did not understood from my above comment and need to be clarified? I can see now that I missed the final double quotes in the suggested debugging line. It must be Debug.Print Dir("C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"), If it returns an empty string, try Debug.Print Dir("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe").
